Microsoft Graph API Get my Events api not working
on miscrosoft graph api they provide v1.0 and v2.0
with v1.0 we used code as they provided on doc, but it does not work and we are not able to access token.
and everywhere they just mentioned all apis that are in v1.0 there is no example of adding calendar event with v2.0.
infect i have used their postman collection and used that one for generating token.
its generated token successfully.
but when i used api that get my calendar events its returns me
{
    "error": {
        "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
        "message": "The tenant for tenant guid 'f3fd3de8-d438-4470-b351-5a7dde989db8' does not exist.",
        "innerError": {
            "oAuthEventOperationId": "10aaa007-edfb-4d36-ab46-d68e51af1e28",
            "oAuthEventcV": "bFc6s7xHD3sZPpSDf6Ve5Q.1.1",
            "errorUrl": "https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant",
            "requestId": "41ca535c-2339-4e95-8915-2f1cdda88231",
            "date": "2024-06-10T06:12:02"
        }
    }
}

i have searched lots of example and documents but i don't get any solution.
at the end i found that token which i have generated is correct one but when i call any calendar addd or get event api its gives me this error.
i have added all full permission to the app for the calendars.
It should add event to calendar
some of dynamic value we have to added those variables.
$url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/$row_comp->ol_tenant_id/oauth2/authorize?client_id=$row_comp->ol_client_id&response_type=code&redirect_uri=$url_auth&response_mode=query&scope=api://$row_comp->ol_client_id/Calendars.ReadWrite%20offline_access&state=12345";

above one is the url.
and on auth url i have added curl request
 $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token";

$data = [
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'scope' => "Calendars.ReadBasic openid profile offline_access",
    'code' => $authorizationCode,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret
];

$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ],
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg='1 :. Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);






$responseData = json_decode($response, true);
$full_object['first_call']=json_decode($response);
if (isset($responseData['error'])) {
    $error_msg= "1 :. Error: " . $responseData['error_description'] . "\n";
} else {
    if(isset($responseData['refresh_token']))
    {
        $ol_access_token_old=$responseData['access_token'];
        $ol_refresh_token_old=$responseData['refresh_token'];
        $accessToken = $responseData['access_token'];
        $refreshToken = $responseData['refresh_token'];
    }
}

And then call refresh token
if($refreshToken!="")
{
    $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    $params=[];
    $params['url']=$url;
    $params['clientId']=$clientId;
    $params['refreshToken']=$refreshToken;
    $params['clientSecret']=$clientSecret;
    $res_data=RefreshToeknOutlook($params);

    

        
                $full_object['second_call']=$res_data['full_res'];
                $error_msg=$res_data['error_msg'];
            
                $ol_access_token_new=$res_data['ol_access_token_new'];
                $ol_refresh_token_new=$res_data['ol_refresh_token_new'];
                $ol_token_expiry_date=$res_data['ol_token_expiry_date'];

        if($ol_access_token_new!="" && $error_msg=="")
        {
            $dt=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $ol_token_expiry_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($dt." +".$ol_token_expiry_date." seconds"));
            $sql_update="update tbl_admin set ol_authorization_code='".$db->real_escape_string($code)."'";
            $sql_update.=",ol_access_token_old='".$db->real_escape_string($ol_access_token_old)."'";
            $sql_update.=",ol_refresh_token_old='".$db->real_escape_string($ol_refresh_token_old)."'";
            $sql_update.=",ol_access_token_new='".$db->real_escape_string($ol_access_token_new)."'";
            $sql_update.=",ol_refresh_token_new='".$db->real_escape_string($ol_refresh_token_new)."'";
            $sql_update.=",ol_token_expiry_date='".$db->real_escape_string($ol_token_expiry_date)."'";
            $sql_update.=",ol_log_text='".$db->real_escape_string(json_encode($full_object))."'";
            $sql_update.=" where id='".$row_comp->id."'";
            
            $db->query($sql_update);
            
            
            
            
            
        }
}

The above function returns token.
and using that i am calling
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

but it returns
{
"error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid 'f3fd3de8-d438-4470-b351-5a7dde989db8' does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
        "oAuthEventOperationId": "10aaa007-edfb-4d36-ab46-d68e51af1e28",
        "oAuthEventcV": "bFc6s7xHD3sZPpSDf6Ve5Q.1.1",
        "errorUrl": "https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant",
        "requestId": "41ca535c-2339-4e95-8915-2f1cdda88231",
        "date": "2024-06-10T06:12:02"
    }
}

}

Could you include how you generated the access token? What grant_type you used to get token?

Ya sure. updting those details on question wait

@Sridevi i have updated question with detail

Are you using personal Microsoft account like Outlook?

@Sridevi yes. one of my account i have registered with outlook which is from gmail

In Portal, what account type you selected while registering Azure AD application?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Sridevi
i need help on generating refresh token
prnt.sc/zaudnSFYhecT

The error occurred as you registered application with supported account type as "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)" that won't work with personal Microsoft accounts.
To resolve the error, you need to create app registration with below account type that supports users to login with personal Microsoft accounts:

Now, I added Calendars.Read permission of Delegated type in my application as below:

To get code value, I ran below authorization request with /common endpoint in Incognito browser that asked user to login like this:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=appId
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=Calendars.Read
&state=12345


When you enter personal Microsoft account like outlook mail, it will take you to login.live.com page:

After successful authentication, it will give code value in address bar starts with 'M.C51' for outlook accounts like this:

Now, I used this code to get access token using authorization code flow via Postman with below parameters and got response like this:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
scope:Calendars.Read
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms

Response:

When I used this token to call API, I got the response successfully with events like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

Response:


can you please show me where i can find appId ?

You can find it in app registration's Overview page named Application (client) Id.

@NileshDaldra Glad to know it worked : )

i have tried to another account but we are getting error 1 :. Error: AADSTS70000: The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired. The user must first sign in and grant the client application access to the requested scope. Trace ID: 2082d941-8805-495f-b734-1bfe5bfde901 Correlation ID: f0932962-017c-474a-850d-3be2ccd52b6b Timestamp: 2024-06-11 13:32:09Z

@NileshDaldra Could you add the error image here and more details like what scope used?
Did you grant admin consent to the added Delegated permissions?

Its working now, it was grant type issue

there i need help. for SSO

Yes, please post new question with more details and share link here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78718998/microsoft-graph-api-login-with-sso-not-working @Sridevi

@NileshDaldra Please add azure tag in that question and include more details what exactly you mean by SSO here? Are you referring any blogs or documents? Please include those too

@NileshDaldra How are you generating the access token? What authentication flow you are currently using?
